# Android notifications overlap each other

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I have two services who both create notifications independently from each other. But when I start them both, **They are like "fighting"(go up and down) for the position**. I hope anyone knows how to fix it. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: May be both notification id will be same try to change the notification id to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is it happening everytime? If they are constantly changing positions you can set the priority of the notifications.Set the priority of one of the notification to be more than other

Comment: notificationManager.notify("change this id", builder.build()); try to change the id.

Comment: Ok that fixed it, but now I have two notifications for each service, because i want to call startForeground() too...

Comment: I have a similar problem right now.. I actually have 6 different items within the same app which can shoot independent notifications.. I set the priority levels of each of the items from 0-5. The ones with priority levels 0 and 1 behaved properly but there was some crazy **fighting** between that of level  2, 3, 4 and 5. I'm guessing the limit for priority levels is 2 right? @AndyDeveloper

Comment: @Taslim I have the same problem at the moment. Have you found a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I tried all sorts of methods. I was eventually able to solve it using *sharedpreferences*. Although this isn't a relatively popular way of doing this, it helps because you can keep track of every notification sent. Here's a code snippet:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Activity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int notificationNumber = prefs.getInt("notificationNumber", 0);


notificationManager.notify(notificationNumber, notification);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
notificationNumber++;
editor.putInt("notificationNumber", notificationNumber);
editor.commit();
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Too late but the solution is to not create a new instance of NotificationCompat.Builder, use the same builder in every updates of your notification to avoid overlapping animation.