# Notifications jumping one over the other on update

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, swap

I have a service that performs several downloads simultaneously in different threads. For each download, a notification with progress is displayed. Progress is updated about once a second. If you run three or more downloads at the same time, when you update the notification, they randomly change their positions in the status bar, jumping one over the other.
I tried setting the priority `setPriority (priority)`, I used `setOnlyAlertOnce (true)`, but this does not help. At the same time, in some other applications I saw that notifications are updated in their places.

The question is, how can this be achieved?

At the moment, my notifications are created like this:

```
private LongSparseArray<Task> mTasksArray = new LongSparseArray<>();
private int notifyId = 0;
...

//setup notification id on task download start
private void initTask(long taskId) {
    Task task = new Task();
    ...
    task.setNotificationId(notifyId++);
    mTasksArray.put(taskId, task);
}

...

//notification update, called about once a second for every running download
private void showNotify(Task task) {
    int notificationId = task.getNotificationId();
    Notification notification = getProgressNotification(task);

    mNotifyManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}

@NonNull
private Notification getProgressNotification(Task task) {
    int max = task.getTotal();
    int count = task.getCount();

    /**
     * using id of notification as priority, but actual priority values can be only from -2 to 2
     * right now it can show three first downloads correctly (for id values 0,1,2), but if,
     * for example, stop first task and start another one, next id and priority will be 3
     * (actually priority will be 2, because max priority is 2) and 3th and 4th notifications
     * will reorder on every update, because of same priority
     */
    int priority = task.getNotificationId();

 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.notif_title_downloading))
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(priority)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_file_download_white_24dp)
            .setProgress(max, count, false)
            .addAction(getPauseAction(task))
            .addAction(getStopAction(task))
            .setContentText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d/%d", count, max));
    return builder.build();
}
```

Updated.

Comment: Seems like duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675273/android-notifications-overlap-each-other

Comment: @toshkinl, But there is no answer, the only answer there is about how to set different ids for notifications. And i have another problem.

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by "jumping one over other"? I am not really sure if I get what's your problem.

Comment: @hardartcore Three or more notifications are updated approximately once a second. If you open the status bar, every time you update any of the notifications, it tries to take the top position in the status bar. You can say they are "fighting" for the first place in the status bar.

Comment: So as far as I understand you the problem is that the notifications don't keep their position depending on that which one was fired first, but on every update they get reordered. Can you post a little more info about how you update the progress bar for example or how you download your files?

Comment: @hardartcore Updated my question with code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the same notification builder for each subsequent update. For example:

```
//First time
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(...)
...
notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
//Second time
builder.setProgress(max, count, false);
notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Comment: Yes, it really works as it should, even without priorities. Thank you!